# If rpdate = False Then Line Keeps Crashing Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of code that keeps crashing Excel.

```
Public Sub Main_Runtime()
rpdate = ToolPack.getDateFromInput()
If rpdate = False Then
    MsgBox ("Macro Cancelled")
    Exit Sub
```

This is a portion of my module, but everytime I run it, it causes Excel to instantly freeze and crash when it hits the line "If rpdate = False Then". I ran a step by step test, and at that line was each freeze (for certain modules that had this line). 
The only work around I was provided before inheriting these VBA projects was that you have to copy then paste the entire module for this to work. After I do that, the code will work each time I run them unless I close the project. Then I must repeat the copy and paste step to have Excel not freeze.

EDIT: 
This is the specific module that I am having to copy and paste in its entirety:

```
Public Sub Main_Runtime()
rpdate = ToolPack.getDateFromInput()
If rpdate = False Then
    MsgBox ("Macro Cancelled")
    Exit Sub
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'start error log
ErrorLog = Format(rpdate, "mm/dd/yy") & " KPI Started at: " & Now & vbNewLine
'Set Global Variables
Set KPIworkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set dayX = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Day " & day(rpdate))
Set ActiveAgentTracker = getworkbook(ActiveAgentTrackerFile)
Set AgentInfo = ActiveAgentTracker.Sheets("Agent")
Set supportInfo = ActiveAgentTracker.Sheets("Support")
Set archiveInfo = ActiveAgentTracker.Sheets("Support")
Dim errormail As Outlook.MailItem
Set errormail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
On Error Resume Next
With errormail
    .Display
    .Subject = "Error Log - " & rpdate
    .Body = ""
End With
'    Set errormail = Nothing

If AgentInfo.AutoFilterMode Then AgentInfo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

Call ResetDay(rpdate)
dayX.Visible = xlSheetVisible

Call InitOverallWrap(rpdate)
Call ImportRawCMSData(rpdate)
Call ImportOverallWrap(rpdate)
Call ImportRawProxyData(rpdate)
Call UpdateInfractionAgents(ThisWorkbook)
Call TransferInfractions(rpdate)
errormail.Body = errormail.Body & vbNewLine & ErrorLog
ErrorLog = ""

With dayX
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A4:BW4").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="<>SLS"
    .Range("A4:BW4").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
    .Activate
    .Range("A5").Activate
    .Range("A2").Value = rpdate
End With

Call RunAgentSummary(KPIworkbook)
Call ImportAttendanceData(rpdate)
Call Import_OB_IB_QA
Call Run_ATL_Summary

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ActiveAgentTracker.Close savechanges:=False
KPIworkbook.Save

ErrorLog = ErrorLog & vbNewLine & "KPI Completed at: " & Now
errormail.Body = errormail.Body & vbNewLine & ErrorLog
ErrorLog = ""

Set errormail = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the code for this, please, `ToolPack.getDateFromInput()`. Also, what type of variable is `rpdate` defined as. And what is the value of `rpdate` if you hover over it before hitting the `If ...` line

Comment: `If rpdate = False Then MsgBox ("Macro Cancelled")` needs to be one line of code. Alternatively you need to add a line with `End If` after the `MsgBox` line.